# Adding bookmark to web browser from external applications

Tags: c#, powershell

Does anyone know if it is possible to add bookmark to web browsers (Safari, IE, FF, Chrome, Opera) from external applications ?

Comment: Probably you can modify the file that those browser uses to store the bookmark. I have some doubt about those browsers supporting adding bookmark from cmdline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **IE** :

You need to create a link file here :

c#

```
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites)
```

Powershell

```
 [Environment]::GetFolderPath( [System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Favorites)
```

**Chrome:**

You need to add entry in  json format file `bookmarks` (with no extension):

on `Win7` is

```
C:\Users\<YOURUSERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\
```

**Firefox:**

The bookmarks are stored in a `SQLite`:

```
../Application Data/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/{your firefox profile}/places.sqlite
```

Using `System.Data.SQLite` you can try to add link, but I can't help you more.

Can't help you for Safari and Opera

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell V2 ISE (x86), this code will list all the Special Folders on the system or even [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/06/08/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-query-the-contents-of-a-special-folder-on-a-windows-7-computer.aspx) -

```
$objShell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
$objShell.SpecialFolders | WHERE {$_.ToString() -match "Fav"}
```

You can then access & manipulate the C:\Users\username\Favorites folder. I don't know if this will extend to all browsers [except IE]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with for adding bookmarks to Chrome from PowerShell:

```
$fileBookmarks="$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
$dataBookmarks=Get-Content $fileBookmarks -Encoding UTF8| Out-String |ConvertFrom-Json
function createNewChromeBookmark ($Bookmarks, [string]$BookmarkName, [string]$BookmarkURL) {
    function getBookmarkIDs($object){
        $object | ForEach-Object{
            "{0:0000}" -f [int]($_.id);
            if([bool]($_.PSobject.Properties.name -match "children")){
                GetBookmarkIDs($_.children);
            }
        }
    };
    $nextBookmarkID = [int](getBookmarkIDs -object $Bookmarks.roots.bookmark_bar|Sort-Object -Descending|Select-Object -First 1) + 1
    $currentChomeTime=[System.DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()*10000;
    $newBookmark= [PSCustomObject]@{
        date_added=$currentChomeTime
        guid=[guid]::NewGuid()
        id=$nextBookMarkID
        name="$BookmarkName"
        type="url"
        url="$BookmarkURL"
    }
    return $newBookmark;
}
$newBookmark = createNewChromeBookmark -Bookmarks $dataBookmarks -BookmarkName "Your Bookmark Name" -BookmarkURL "https://[Your URL Here]";
$dataBookmarks.roots.bookmark_bar.children += $newBookmark;
$dataBookmarksJSON = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $dataBookmarks -Depth 200
Set-Content -Path $fileBookmarks -Value $dataBookmarksJSON -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: The solution is working fine, one small addition I needed, how to create folder if not exist in bookmark manager, in case folder exists then add bookmark in it, else create folder and then add bookmark, I am not getting success of creating folder

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the script! Modified it to add a folder:

```
$fileBookmarks="$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
$dataBookmarks=Get-Content $fileBookmarks -Encoding UTF8| Out-String |ConvertFrom-Json
function createNewChromeBookmarkFolder ($Bookmarks, [string]$FolderName) {
    function getBookmarkIDs($object){
        $object | ForEach-Object{
            "{0:0000}" -f [int]($_.id);
            if([bool]($_.PSobject.Properties.name -match "children")){
                GetBookmarkIDs($_.children);
            }
        }
    };
    $nextBookmarkID = [int](getBookmarkIDs -object $Bookmarks.roots.bookmark_bar|Sort-Object -Descending|Select-Object -First 1) + 1
    $children=@();
    $currentChomeTime=[System.DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()*10000;    
    $newBookmark= [PSCustomObject]@{
        children=$children
        date_added=$currentChomeTime
        guid=[guid]::NewGuid()
        id=$nextBookMarkID
        name="$FolderName"
        type="folder"        
    }
    return $newBookmark;
}
$newBookmark = createNewChromeBookmarkFolder -Bookmarks $dataBookmarks -FolderName "My Folder Name";
$dataBookmarks.roots.bookmark_bar.children += $newBookmark;
$dataBookmarksJSON = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $dataBookmarks -Depth 100
Set-Content -Path $fileBookmarks -Value $dataBookmarksJSON -Encoding UTF8
```